# how to delete all cells

Tags: ios, swift

hi im trying to custom apple's sample code.

here's a problem :

i want to delete all cells when i touch button(reset).  when i touch button it looks work well but if i reload this summeryView, cell and its data comes again/./.. i spent pretty a lot time, but i don't know how to delete cell data after reload summeryView.. please help. thank you for read my question. hava a great day.

here's a summeryView code
'''

```
import UIKit



/// Displays a table view of the actions with the time duration for each.
class SummaryViewController: UIViewController {
   
    /// The summary view controller's primary view.
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var resetSync: UIButton!
    /// The list of actions, sorted by descending time.
    private var sortedActions = [String]()
    
    var isSelected: Int = 0
    
    

    /// The times of each action, keyed by the action's name.
    var actionFrameCounts: [String: Int]? {
        didSet {
            guard let frameCounts = actionFrameCounts else { return }

            // Clear out the previous list of actions.
            sortedActions.removeAll()

            // Create a list of the actions sorted by descending time.
            let sortedElements = frameCounts.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }
            sortedElements.forEach { entry in sortedActions.append(entry.key) }
        }
    }

    /// A closure the summary view controller calls after it disappears.
    var dismissalClosure: (() -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
        
        

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        
//        sortedActions.removeAll()
        
        
        if isSelected == 1 {
            sortedActions.removeAll()
        } else if isSelected == 0 {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
   

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        
        // Call the dismissal closure, if there is one.
        dismissalClosure?()
        
        
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func resetTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        //self.deleteButtonDelegate?.deletePressed(in: self)
        sortedActions.removeAll()
        tableView.dataSource = nil
        tableView.reloadData()
        
        isSelected = 1
        
        
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View Data Source
extension SummaryViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sortedActions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let customCellName = "SummaryCellPrototype"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellName,
                                                 for: indexPath)

        guard let summaryCell = cell as? SummaryTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Not an instance of `SummaryTableViewCell`.")
        }

        if let frameCounts = actionFrameCounts {
            let frameRate = ExerciseClassifier.frameRate

            let action = sortedActions[indexPath.row]
            let totalFrames = frameCounts[action] ?? 0
            let totalDuration = Double(totalFrames) / frameRate

            summaryCell.totalDuration = totalDuration
            summaryCell.actionLabel.text = action
        }

        return summaryCell
    }
    
    //slide delete
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            sortedActions.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table Cell
///Displays the name of an action and the total time duration of that action.
///
///

class SummaryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   
    
    

    /// Displays name of the action.
    @IBOutlet weak var actionLabel: UILabel!

    /// Displays the amount of time of the action.
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    /// Converts the floating point value into a string for the action label.
    ///
    /// For example, the time label shows "1.7s" for a value of `1.66666666666`.
    var totalDuration: Double = 0 {
        didSet { timeLabel.text = String(format: "%0.1fs", totalDuration) }
    }
   
   
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sortedActions array empty and reload table on button reset action and remove the line datasource = nil

Comment: i remove the code "tableView.dataSource = nil" but still cell data appear again when i reload a summaryView

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
@IBAction func resetTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    sortedActions.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()
    isSelected = 0
}
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work... thank you for your help

Comment: do you mean the tableview cell has not been removed @chamcham

Comment: yep. it seems deleted but, when i reload this view it appears again. i want delete these cells permanently..